# Export Java Swing JTable header to Excel

Tags: java, excel, swing, jtable

In my application, I have exported the table content to Excel already, but the result excludes the table header. Wondering how to export `JTable` to Excel include the table header? I tried couple ways, but still can not see the table header in excel, the following is my code:

```
    defautTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(null,columnNames){
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    // the jTable row are generated dynamically.
    final JTable jTable = new JTable(defautTableModel);

    jTable.setLocation(20,60);
    jTable.setSize(950,450);
    jTable.setRowHeight(25);

    JTableHeader jTableHeader = jTable.getTableHeader();
    jTableHeader.setLocation(20,30);
    jTableHeader.setSize(950,30);
    jTableHeader.setFont(new Font(null, Font.BOLD, 16));
    jTableHeader.setResizingAllowed(true);
    jTableHeader.setReorderingAllowed(true);

    jTable.add(jTableHeader);

    JScrollPane tablePanel = new JScrollPane(jTable);
    tablePanel.setLocation(10,10);
    tablePanel.setSize(960,400);

    // export data to excel method 

    public void exportToExcel(){
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
    for (int i = 0; i < defautTableModel.getRowCount(); i++) {
        Row = sheet.createRow(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < defautTableModel.getColumnCount(); j++) {
            Cell = Row.createCell(j);
            try {
                if (defautTableModel.getValueAt(i,j) != null){
                    Cell.setCellValue(defautTableModel.getValueAt(i,j).toString());
                    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(Constant.Path_TestData_Output);
                    wb.write(fileOut);
                    fileOut.flush();
                    fileOut.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about `defaultTableModel.getColumnName(   )` ?

Comment: This might sound weird, but if you have the time, JasperReports can export to excel itself, which might save you a lot of issues

Comment: @ThomasEdwin, yes ,and I tried to handle the issue like what you say, for now the header has been export to the excel. I add another For loop to handle that, seems cannot handle it inside of the rowCount For loop.thx agian.

Comment: @MadProgrammer , thx for your suggestion, I will take a look at JasperReports, it looks like more powerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only accessing the data columns and you need to get the header ones first.
You can acheive it by different means, either you use the method `getColumnName`
as ThomasEdwin mentioned in his comment or use `columnNames` variable that you have provided to your model constructor: `new DefaultTableModel(null,columnNames)`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

**Export Java Swing JTable header with JTable index to Excel**

```js
private static void writeToExcell(DefaultTableModel TabR ,TableColumnModel tableM) throws IOException {
try
{
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
   int retval = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(fileChooser);

   if (retval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
       File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
       if (file != null) {
           if (!file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".xls")) {
               file = new File(file.getParentFile(), file.getName() + ".xls");

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
 Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
 CreationHelper createhelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row row = null;

    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell cell = null;
    

     for (int a=0;a<TabR.getRowCount();a++)
    {
        row = sheet.createRow(a+1); /*  We create an Excel layer Row. 
                We understand how many rows are in 
                TabR with GetRowCount from TabR, the 
                DefaultTableModel of the current JTable, 
                and add one to it.*/
        
        for (int b=0;b<tableM.getColumnCount();b++) 
        {
         cell = row.createCell(b);/*  With the GetColumnCount 
                function of the existing JTable's 
                TableColumnModel, we create more 
                Column in the JTable.*/
         
            cell.setCellValue(TabR.getValueAt(a, b).toString()); /*we give the value of the cell. */
        }
    }
    
    for (int c=0;c<cell.getRowIndex();c++)
    {
        row = sheet.createRow(c);
        
        for (int d=0;d<tableM.getColumnCount();d++) 
        {
             
         cell = row.createCell(d);
            cell.setCellValue(tableM.getColumn(d).getHeaderValue().toString());
 
        }
    }
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    wb.write(out);
    out.close();

       }

       }
       }

} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(B_anaEk.class.getName()).log(Level.ALL, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(B_anaEk.class.getName()).log(Level.ALL, null, ex);
}
```